# Export SoapUI test report in human readable format

Tags: soapui

I try to export a `SoapUI` test report, which contains failed requests, responses and expected results too. I found just a simple list in result window, which contains test steps with result OK or FAILED status like this: `Step 3 [checkHealth] OK: took 10602 ms`.

Comment: Would you mind taking a look at this thread ? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41700437/creating-a-test-report-from-project-level-tear-down-script

Comment: @Rao : It looks better, but it doesn't contain responses and expected responses for SOAP requests.

Comment: Do you want the request and response in Report? That may quickly become non readable. Isn't it?

Comment: @Rao : I would like to get only failed ones, because it would be useful.

Comment: You mean to say that shows the failed response in the report in addition to previously mentioned thread?

Comment: I need to export these in `txt` or maybe in `xls`.

Comment: Soapui already does store the responses automatically for the failed steps.

Comment: I know, but there is no detailed output, which I could export too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160070/discussion-between-rao-and-plaidshirt).